# Implementing basic server using Java Sockets

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

I am following Oracle's java sockets tutorial: [docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html)

```
try (
// ...
PrintWriter out =
    new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
) {
String inputLine, outputLine;

// Initiate conversation with client
KnockKnockProtocol kkp = new KnockKnockProtocol();
outputLine = kkp.processInput(null);
out.println(outputLine);

while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
    outputLine = kkp.processInput(inputLine);
    out.println(outputLine);
    if (outputLine.equals("Bye."))
        break;
}
```

The tutorial states "The readLine method waits until the client responds by writing something to its output stream (the server's input stream)".

But the server's input stream,  "in", was initialized using the client's input stream, not its output stream.

Shouldn't "in" then be initialized with clientSocket.getOutputStream(), to listen to the client's OUTput?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are confusing `client` and `client socket`. The `client` sends some data and the `client socket` reads it in the input stream.

The server program has two types of sockets:

- one `ServerSocket` - its job is to listen for connections
- one or more `Socket`s (named client sockets in the Oracle example); the server reads data from its input stream and writes data to its output stream.

The client program only needs to use one regular `Socket`.

Comment: since a socket is one endpoint in this client server link http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/, I would think clientSocket is a representation of the client.  

Therefore if a client writes an outputStream the server reads from, the server should listen to clientSocket's outputStream.  I don't understand why client and clientSocket are NOT synonymous.

Comment: @HukeLau_DABA: Let's say you connect to google.com. The client is you. You have a socket opened to talk with Google. And you write to your socket output stream. At the other side, in the google datacenter, google, the server, has a socket for you. And Google receives the messages you sent by reading them from this socket input stream.

Answer (score 0):

Each client writes to an output stream. Messages written by a client to its output stream goes to the server which reads it from an input stream associated with this client socket.

The server also has an output stream for each client socket. Messages written to this output stream by the server can be read by the client using its input stream:

```
                       output stream ----------> input stream
server client1 socket                                          client 1 socket
                       input stream <----------- output stream



                       output stream ----------> input stream
server client2 socket                                          client 2 socket
                       input stream <----------- output stream
```